# Flutter Quick Actions: quick_action_getlaunchaction_no_activity

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart

Today I found an issue in my application which happens with the quick_actions plugin provided for Flutter.  I found this issue through my Firebase Crashlytics dashboard, I have been unable to reproduce this issue while using quick actions.

This is my Android Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.freecodecamp">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
    <application android:label="freeCodeCamp"
        android:icon="@mipmap/launcher_icon"
        android:enableOnBackInvokedCallback="true">
        <activity android:name="com.ryanheise.audioservice.AudioServiceActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
            android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <meta-data android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
                android:resource="@style/NormalTheme" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name="com.ryanheise.audioservice.AudioService"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.media.browse.MediaBrowserService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <receiver android:name="com.ryanheise.audioservice.MediaButtonReceiver"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below. This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

This is my QuickActions service (I run the Init when starting my app from the main.dart file):

```
import 'package:freecodecamp/app/app.locator.dart';
import 'package:freecodecamp/app/app.router.dart';
import 'package:quick_actions/quick_actions.dart';
import 'package:stacked_services/stacked_services.dart';

class QuickActionsService {
  static final QuickActionsService _quickActionsService =
      QuickActionsService._internal();

  QuickActions quickActions = const QuickActions();

  final NavigationService _navigationService = locator<NavigationService>();

  factory QuickActionsService() {
    return _quickActionsService;
  }

  Future<void> init() async {
    await quickActions.setShortcutItems([
      const ShortcutItem(
        type: 'action_tutorials',
        localizedTitle: 'Tutorials',
      ),
      const ShortcutItem(
        type: 'action_learn',
        localizedTitle: 'Learn',
      ),
      const ShortcutItem(
        type: 'action_code_radio',
        localizedTitle: 'Code Radio',
      ),
      const ShortcutItem(
        type: 'action_podcasts',
        localizedTitle: 'Podcasts',
      ),
    ]);

    await quickActions.initialize((shortcutType) {
      switch (shortcutType) {
        case 'action_tutorials':
          _navigationService.replaceWith(Routes.homeView);
          break;
        case 'action_learn':
          _navigationService.replaceWith(Routes.learnLandingView);
          break;
        case 'action_code_radio':
          _navigationService.replaceWith(Routes.codeRadioView);
          break;
        case 'action_podcasts':
          _navigationService.replaceWith(Routes.podcastListView);
          break;
        default:
      }
    });
  }

  QuickActionsService._internal();
}
```

This is the error in the Crashlytics Dashboard:

```
Fatal Exception: io.flutter.plugins.firebase.crashlytics.FlutterError: PlatformException(quick_action_getlaunchaction_no_activity, There is no activity available when launching action, null, null)
       at StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope(message_codecs.dart:653)
       at MethodChannel._invokeMethod(platform_channel.dart:315)
       at QuickActionsAndroid.initialize(quick_actions_android.dart:32)
       at QuickActionsService.init(quick_actions_service.dart:38)
       at .main(main.dart:42)
```

main.dart init function:

```
Future<void> main({bool testing = false}) async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  setupLocator();

  var fbApp = await Firebase.initializeApp(
      options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
  if (!testing) {
    FlutterError.onError = FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordFlutterFatalError;
    PlatformDispatcher.instance.onError = (error, stack) {
      FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordError(error, stack, fatal: true);
      return true;
    };
    if (kReleaseMode) {
      await fbApp.setAutomaticDataCollectionEnabled(true);
    } else {
      await fbApp.setAutomaticDataCollectionEnabled(false);
    }
  }
  await AuthenticationService().init();
  await NotificationService().init();
  await AppAudioService().init();
  await FkUserAgent.init();
  await QuickActionsService().init();
  runApp(const FreeCodeCampMobileApp());
}
```

Comment: can you share code of main.dart where you called init of quickaction

Comment: I have updated the issue with the init function in the main.dart file. Hope it helps!

Comment: Try to move your quickAction.initilize() method inside the initState of your first app launch page. Suppose HomePage() is the first page of your app then make it statefulWidget and move your quickAction.initilize(){} //without await//  code inside it.